# Getting NullPointerException in reference to protected variable in JUnit Test subclass

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, bazel

I have a subclass `AnswerQuestionTests` which contains several JUnit tests annotated with `@Test` (I'm running JUnit 4). This subclass extends a superclass `TestBase` which has no other test methods, but contains a bunch of `protected` variables. The idea we had was that, in order to reduce code duplication, we would have all of our tests extend `TestBase` to avoid duplicating code for initialization of some mocked services that most of our tests need.

For example, I have a method in `AnswerQuestionTests` which tests whether or not a badge's progress gets incremented in the database:

```
@Test
public void testBadgeProgressIncremented() {
    int badgeProgressBeforeAction = clientModule.badgeClient().getCurrentBadgeActivity();
    ...
}
```

In this case, `clientModule` is a `protected` variable which is declared in the superclass `TestBase`. This variable gets initialized in an `initialize()` method in `TestBase`, which is called from `AnswerQuestionTests` using a `@BeforeAll` annotation:

```
public class AnswerQuestionTests extends TestBase {
    @BeforeAll
    public void initialize() {
        super.initialize();
    }
    ...
}
```

I run this test using Bazel's [`java_test`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_test) rule, which takes a `test_class` as a parameter, and I give it the `AnswerQuestionTest` class. However, the runner produces a `NullPointerException` in reference to `clientModule` and all of the other `protected` variables declared in the superclass.

I assume this has something to do with my lack of knowledge about how the JUnit runner works, but can anybody offer any advice?

EDIT: I also annotate `AnswerQuestionTests` with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` so that the JUnit runner only creates a new instance once per class instead of once per method.

EDIT 2: The issue was that the Bazel `java_test` runner natively runs JUnit4, but all of our tests were previously written under the assumption of using JUnit5. Resolved.

Comment: `@TestInstance` is not available in junit4. Sounds like you are mixing junit4 and junit5

Comment: Ah yeah, my runner was using JUnit4 but I was unaware of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In junit4 this annotation is called `@BeforeClass` and should be on a `static` method. It is executed before all test methods in this class are executed. Junit5 annotation will be ignored in junit4

For each method execution Junit creates a new instance of `AnswerQuestionTests`, so you can't use instance fields in `@BeforeClass`.

One option would be to store the initialized client in a static field.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that I annotate this class with `@TestInstance(LifeCycle.PER_CLASS)` so that it creates a new instance only once per class. Does this change anything?

Comment: @DylanPowers thanks, was not aware this annotations exists in junit5. Always prefered the testng aproach for testinstances.